# how to use the default android contacts ui to show private contact information

Tags: android, contacts

I am writing an application that allows users to create private contacts that wont be stored in the default contacts app in android. Is there a way i can reuse the default android contacts UI to display these private contacts?

Comment: it can be done on API > 14(you need to build `ContentProvider` and this information can be showned using `QuickContact.showQuickContact`) but it's not supported ... sample app(will work only on ICS) http://selvin.pl/QCTest.apk

Comment: ... and source http://selvin.pl/QCTest.zip

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nevertheless, I am coding in API 10. I've tried creating and deleting contacts on the spot, a bit slow in the creation, but at least it's working.